# Helm Range can't iterate over map

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Having the following template code

```yaml
{{- define "test.mergedEnvVars" -}}
{{- if eq .Values.resourcesProfile "performance" }}
{{- merge .Values.perfEnvVars .Values.envVars }}
{{- else }}
{{- .Values.envVars }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And the following use of it

```yaml
{{- range $name, $value := (include "test.mergedEnvVars" .)  }}
{{- if (typeIs "string" $value) }}
- name: {{ $name }}
  value: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- else }}
- name: {{ $name }}
  {{- toYaml $value | nindent 14 }}
{{- end }}
```

I am getting an error
`executing "test/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.>: range can't iterate over map[TIMEOUTS: 60 OPTIONS: -Xm200 -xS200... and so on]`

Variables envVars and envPerfVars are just a maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Go `text/template` language, `define`d template functions always produce strings.  `include` is a Helm extension, but it calls the function and returns a string.  There's no way to return any other type.

The `map[key: value]` syntax is a default serialization of Go map objects.  There's no way to convert back from that to an actual map representation.

In short: in the `text/template` language, and by extension in Helm, you can't write a function that returns a map, and correspondingly you can't `range (include ...)` to loop over a function's return value.

---

For the very specific case you're using, though, there is a useful Helm alternative.  When you install a chart, you can provide an additional set of values using the `helm install -f` option, and these override what's in the chart's `values.yaml` file.

So, say your chart has

```yaml
# values.yaml
envVars:
  - name: THREADS
    value: "1"
```

But if you run

```bash
helm install my-application . -f performance.yaml
```

where the `-f` file has

```yaml
# performance.yaml
envVars:
  - name: THREADS
    value: "16"
```

then the `envVars` in the override file will take precedence over the original file.

The merge rules for lists of key-value pairs might not be what you expect (even using `merge`) and you also might find it better to have Helm-level settings for key values

```yaml
threads: 1
```

```yaml
env:
  - name: THREADS
    value: {{ quote .Values.threads }}
```

than to try to put free-form Kubernetes YAML fragments into Helm settings.